# How do i open developers tools using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

How do i open developers tools using robot framework and then switch to network tab and fetch a URL from the network tab. I have written below code but it does nothing. Could someone please help me

```
Open Browser    https://my.doe.nh.gov/myNHDOE/Login/Login.aspx  ie
Maximize Browser Window     
Input Text  //*[@id='ctl00_MenuingMasterContent_txtAccountID']  uname
Input Text  //*[@id='ctl00_MenuingMasterContent_txtPassword']   pwd
Click Element   //*[@id='ctl00_MenuingMasterContent_btnLogin_lbCenter'] 
Sleep   5s  
Press Key   //*[@id='ctl00_MenuingMasterContent_ctl03_lnkLink1']    \\123
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible. From Chrome Driver help center (refer link)

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/devtools-window-keeps-closing

When you open the DevTools window, ChromeDriver is automatically disconnected. When ChromeDriver receives a command, if disconnected, it will attempt to close the DevTools window and reconnect.

If you need to inspect something in DevTools, the best you can do now is pause your test so that ChromeDriver won't close DevTools. When you are done inspecting things in Chrome, you can unpause your test and ChromeDriver will close the window and continue.